# How to divide multiple columns of a dataframe with a single column from another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a table as shown below

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 40 | 30 |
| 20 | 50 | 20 |

I have another dataframe with a single column

| Column D |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 10 |

I need to perform a division of every column in the first dataframe with the column from the second dataframe. The output should appear something like below

| Column E | Column F | Column G |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 20 | 15 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 |

What is the easiest way to do this? I tried

```
df1.div(df2)
```

I tried variations using the div function but it didn't yield proper results. I could try iterating every column of the first dataframe and then dividing it but I was wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

When dividing a DataFrame by Another DataFrame pandas expects the columns to be the same. If you want to divide all the columns of the first DataFrame by a single column you should perform the difision  by a Series:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Column A": [10, 20], "Column B": [40, 50], "Column C": [30, 20]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Column D": [2, 10]})

df1.div(df2["Column D"], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

A way of producing your result without manually iterating over every column could be:

```
df1.div(df2.values)
```

where

`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA': [10, 20], 'ColumnB': [40, 50], 'ColumnC': [30, 20]})`

and

`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnD': [2, 10]})`

Answer (score 0):

another approach to divide multiple columns of one DataFrame with a single column from another DataFrame is by using broadcasting. Here's an example:
import pandas as pd

```
# Create the first DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column A': [10, 20],
    'Column B': [40, 50],
    'Column C': [30, 20]
})

# Create the second DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column D': [2, 10]
})

# Divide each column in df1 with the column from df2 using broadcasting
result = df1 / df2['Column D'].values[:, None]

# Rename the columns of the result DataFrame
result.columns = ['Column E', 'Column F', 'Column G']

# Print the result
print(result)
```